# Binding to DependencyProperty with no result

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have problem with binding to dependency property of my new control.
I decided to write some tests to examine this issue.

**Binding from TextBox.Text to another TextBox.Text**

XAML code:

```
<TextBox Name="Test" Text="{Binding ElementName=Test2, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Name="Test2" Grid.Row="2" />
```

The result is good - when I writing something in first TextBox -> second TextBox is updating (conversely too).

[image]

I created new control -> for example "SuperTextBox" with dependency property "SuperValue".

Control XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.SuperTextBox"
             ...
             Name="Root">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SuperValue, ElementName=Root, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class SuperTextBox : UserControl
{
    public SuperTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SuperValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SuperValue",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(SuperTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
    );

    public string SuperValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SuperValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SuperValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Ok, and now tests!

**Binding from TextBox.Text to SuperTextBox.SuperValue**

```
    <TextBox x:Name="Test1" Text="{Binding ElementName=Test2, Path=SuperValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <local:SuperTextBox x:Name="Test2" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

Test is correct too!
When I writing something in TextBox, SuperTextBox is updating.
When i writing in SuperTextBox, TextBox is updating.
All is ok!

Now a problem:
**Binding from SuperTextBox.SuperValue to TextBox.Text**

```
    <TextBox x:Name="Test1"/>
    <local:SuperTextBox x:Name="Test2" SuperValue="{Binding ElementName=Test1, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

In this case, when I writing something in SuperTextBox, TextBox is not updating!
[image]

How can I fix this?

PS: Question is very very long, I am sorry for that, but i tried exactly describe my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why one works and the other doesn't is because the `Text` dependency property of `TextBox` is defined to bind `TwoWay` by default, while your dependency property `SuperValue` isn't. You need to use TwoWay-binding if you want the destination to update the source in addition to the source updating the destination.

To fix this, you can add `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` to `SuperValue's` metadata like so:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SuperValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SuperValue",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(SuperTextBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
);
```

Comment: Oh, one another case still doesn't work. Can You check new version of question - I added section "Edit1".

Comment: Sorry, but i thought that this both questions are very similar and it is no need to create new "topic".

I am deleted the "accepted answer" because It can creates illusion that "topic is end".

But ok, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Change binding mode into TwoWay.

Comment: Thanks! It is works!
But, why in first and second case code works without "Mode=TwoWay"?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx Here is an explanation... TextBox Text "Defaults" to BindingMode.TwoWay. Your property does not.

Answer (score 1):

Since in first two cases `Test1` knows when it needs to update itself but not in third case. Only `Test2` knows that when it should update in third case. That's why `TwoWay` mode is required in third case.

**EDIT**

- First case is working since behind the scenes,xaml hook to
  `AddValueChanged` event exposed by the `PropertyDescriptor`. For the
  reason it's working refer to this link [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/12/17/puff-the-magic-poco-binding-and-inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf).

Comment: But in first case I can write in second box (which does not have any information about data binding ) and first will be updated.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.